# How can I change an array to a string to display symbols in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Ive got a c++ console game that uses arrays to store symbols for the grid, then couts them. What would be the easiest way to store the array into a string for optimization purposes?
For example this code paints the grid with its current contents, this is updated throughout the program.

```
void paintFloor( const char floor[][SIZEX])
{ 
    SelectBackColour( clBlack);
    SelectTextColour( clWhite);
    Gotoxy(0, 2);
    for (int y( 0); y < (SIZEY); ++y)       
    {   for (int x( 0); x < (SIZEX); ++x)   
        {   
            cout << floor[y][x];            
        } 
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: for optimization? please read up the term premature optimization

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them into an array of strings. like you can do, string stri; to create a string , and you can print it normally using cout<< str[i];